# How can I pass a variables name, not its value. Then use its value after it has been passed?

Tags: c#

Im wanting to pass in these strings into a loop, I want the variable list splitSearchString[i] to be passed as the variable itself not its value. Once In the loop i want to use its value. Is this possible or am I approaching this problem the wrong way? Thanks for helping out a newb.
Here's the code:

```
    string[] splitSearchString = SearchText.Split(' ');
        int i = 0;
        switch (SearchBy)
        {
            case 1:
                SearchByString = "cert_code LIKE '%" + splitSearchString[i] + "%'";
                break;
            case 2:
                SearchByString = "upc LIKE '%" + splitSearchString[i] + "%'";
                break;
            case 3:
                SearchByString = "description LIKE '%" + splitSearchString[i] + "%'";
                break;
            case 4:
                SearchByString = "(cert_code LIKE '%" + splitSearchString[i] + "%' OR upc LIKE '%" + splitSearchString[i] + "%')";
                break;
            case 5:
                SearchByString = "(cert_code LIKE '%" + splitSearchString[i] + "%' OR description LIKE '%" + splitSearchString[i] + "%')";
                break;
            case 6:
                SearchByString = "(upc LIKE '%" + splitSearchString[i] + "%' OR description LIKE '%" + splitSearchString[i] + "%')";
                break;
            default:
                SearchByString = "(upc LIKE '%" + splitSearchString[i] + "%' OR description LIKE '%" + splitSearchString[i] + "%' OR cert_code LIKE '%" + splitSearchString[i] + "%')";
                break;
        }
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        sqlConn.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd;
            if (searchString.Contains(' ') == true && SearchExact == false)
            {
                formatedSplitSearchString = "SELECT CASE WHEN t1.longdesc IS NULL OR t1.longdesc = '' THEN t1.desc WHEN t1.longdesc IS NOT NULL AND t1.longdesc <> '' THEN t1.longdesc END AS 'description', t1.upcode FROM Product t1 LEFT JOIN Vendor t2 ON t1.vendor = t2.vendor_no LEFT JOIN Department t3 ON t1.department = t3.dept_no LEFT JOIN Section t4 on t1.section = t4.section WHERE " + SearchByString + VendorFilterStr + DeptFilterStr + SectionFilterStr;
                for (i = 0; i < splitSearchString.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        formatedSplitSearchString += " AND " + SearchByString;
                    }
                }
                formatedSplitSearchString += VendorFilterStr + DeptFilterStr + SectionFilterStr + ";";
                sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(formatedSplitSearchString, sqlConn);
            }
            else
            {
                sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(
                "SELECT CASE WHEN t1.longdesc IS NULL OR t1.longdesc = '' THEN t1.description WHEN t1.longdesc IS NOT NULL AND t1.longdesc <> '' THEN t1.longdesc END AS 'description', t1.upcode FROM Product t1 LEFT JOIN Vendor t2 ON t1.vendor = t2.vendor_no LEFT JOIN Sections t4 on t1.section = t4.section LEFT JOIN Departments t3 ON t1.department = t3.dept_no WHERE " + SearchByString + VendorFilterStr + DeptFilterStr + SectionFilterStr + ";", sqlConn);
            }
        }
        SqlDataReader sqlDr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sqlDr.Read())
        {
            lvi = new ListViewItem((sqlDr["description"].ToString()));
            lvi.SubItems.Add(sqlDr["upc"].ToString());
            lviList.Add(lvi);
        }
        return lviList;
```

Comment: *"am I approaching this problem the wrong way?"* Yes. The names you use in your program (classes, variables, enums) are for *your* use, not for your program's. If you need to associate some data with a string, use a [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

Comment: You really, REALLY should rewrite your whole code to avoid those kind of things. As @JonathonReinhart said, variable names are usually for your use, not the compiler's. Also, your code presents huge vulnerabilities in the form of SQL Injection. I don't know what's the target of the application you're writing, but any user could just put a `%' OR 1 = 1 OR '%` to make your query return the whole table, or terminate it and drop the database, or whatever he wants. As for your question, it's a bit unclear what you really want to do, but just passing the variable to another function should do.

Comment: Just going off of your title, "How can I pass a variables name, not its value. Then use its value after it has been passed?", you MIGHT be able to do that with reflection.  It would depend on scope and a few other things, but it might be possible. However, looking at the body of the question and the code sample, I don't think that's actually what you want to do...

Comment: @SebastianoRoncato Thanks, I'm just writing this as a project to learn. The user is not able to enter in any text the options are limited to what can be selected from a combobox. I understand that I should use parametrized queries if the user is entering information. I think your right though I need to take a step back and redesign this code from the ground up.

Comment: @PhatWrat Do you really think suggesting reflection to a beginning programmer is the right idea?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I'm not so much "suggesting" reflection as I am stating that the title of the question is describing reflection.  As I noted, I really don't think that's what he/she wants to actually do.

Answer (score -2):

So, what you want to do is pass the variable by reference, that way you are passing the actual memory address of the variable.

The better option is to create a function that returns an array, and call the function to set the array.